# Why calling 'super()' in child class constructor?

Tags: java

Why do I need to call `super` here?

```
class Animal {
    public Animal(String arg) {
        System.out.println("Constructing an animal: " + arg);
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    public Dog() {
        super("From Dog constructor");
        System.out.println("Constructing a dog.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Because the compiler won't insert a **default constructor** if you provide a constructor. Thus `Animal` has no empty constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default every class having default constructor i.e non parameterized constuctor, once you define any constructor on it then default behavour will not work.

Another thing is if  any class extends any other class then by default each constructor of child class will call their parrent's default constructor i.e super() internally  but once you declare parameterized constuctor to the parent class then you need to call it from child class constructor explictly i.e super(parameter...)

Answer (score 1):

If the parent constructor has no argument, no reason whatsoever. Otherwise, you need an explicit call to super(...) where you can set those parameters.